# Control + 1 suggestion doesn't work in eclipse scala ide?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I am using eclipse scala ide **Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK Build id: 3.0.4-2.11-20140520-1158-Typesafe** . Suggestions feature seems to be missing from it, like if from my test case I write ***PersonTest.scala***

```
val person = new Person()
```

since *Person* class doesn't exist intially, I get a compilation error . Now in case of java if I press Control + 1 ( suggestion ) I get an option to create a class but in case of scala ide this feature seems to be missing .

Can someone pleas help me if there is an alternative or am I missing something ?

Comment: Note: as mentioned by [sschaef](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2621536/sschaef) in [the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100571/control-1-suggestion-doesnt-work-in-eclipse-scala-ide/25101397?noredirect=1#comment39069018_25101397), Scala IDE 4 will have a quick fix to create a new Scala class. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25101397/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have that option directly available with Scala in Eclipse (Q2 2014).

You can click <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, and select new Scala class instead.

---

However Scala IDE 4 Lithium (Q3 2014) will propose a new [Scala class dialog](http://scala-ide.org/docs/4.0.x/features/wizards/index.html), and the [create method/class quick fix](http://scala-ide.org/docs/4.0.x/features/typingviewing/quick-fixes.html)

[image: http://scala-ide.org/docs/_images/create-method.png]

Comment: Sad that eclipse ide is not having this feature, but your solution is also good enough to save some time.

Comment: In Scala IDE 4 milestones this is supported with CTRL+1.

Comment: @sschaef indeed. Well spotted. I have included the link to that new feature as well as a screenshot in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC - perfect ! You Saved me from an annoying coding practice !!

Comment: This feature is having some bugs, If you try to change the package or source path , although it creates a source file but without any body and IDE is not able to recognize this scala class

Comment: @Shakti I agree. Hopefully this will be fiexed in a future milestone: Scala IDE 4 isn't released yet.